# (Geth) Get Detail Of Dropped Transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to make my own Ethereum Explorer, I am pretty much near now... Right now I am stuck with `Dropped & Replaced` Transactions.

Here's TxHash=`0x621b5b34ccf2960915b4c4a1bf9a002e33f8b780fe1d04d3649d715ad4517948`

In etherscan you can see its `Dropped & Replaced`, but I can't find it in my Geth node.

I can't find this TX in txPool... Can someone tell me where I can get it from.

[image]

My Geth is Fully Synced already.

This is how I am starting Geth::

`geth --datadir=/blockchain/ --mainnet --cache=20480 --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcport 20590 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcapi="eth,net,db,rpc,web3,txpool,personal,debug,account" --http --maxpeers 200 --txpool.globalslots=250000 --txpool.globalqueue=50000`

## SOLUTION::

If anyone interested in doing the same... please note you have to first enable websocket in Geth Node, then subscribe to `pendingTransaction`,`logs`

1. Below is how you can listen to upcoming `pendingTransactions`

   ```
   const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err,res) => {
     if (err) console.error(err);
   });
   subscription.on('data', (txHash) => {
      setTimeout(async () => {
         try {
            let tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
            if (tx) {
               // Here's your Transaction save it somewhere
            }
         } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
         }
   })
   ```
2. Subscribe to `logs`, these logs will tells you either transaction `dropped`, `replaced` or `successful`

> Use can use filters like `fromBlock`, `toBlock`, `address`, `topics` if you want only specific transactions details [Read more here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs)

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    //address: '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7',
}, function(error, result){
    if (error)
      console.log(error);
})
.on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
  console.log("connected", subscriptionId);
})
.on("data", function(log) {
  console.log(log);
  // SAVE data to DB
})
.on("changed", function(log) {
  console.log(log);
  // SAVE data to DB
});
```

> There might be other ways too but I want everything realtime just like
> **etherscan** so I prefer this way.

Answer (score 1):

GoEthereum does not expose this information directly.

You need to implement your own mempool watcher that detects transactions that were later replaced by a higher fee.

Comment: You mean I need to track all the pendingTransaction() myself ? Pls explain a bit

Comment: Exactly like that.